# how to get the average of random numbers

Tags: c#, loops, random

I have a loop that repeats itself 100 times and every time it generates a random number

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        const double MAX = 42.0;
        const double MIN = 34.5;
        double ex4 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
            
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("the average of the degres is: {0}",ex4);
```

And I want to calculate the average of the numbers and print it but I don't know how to store all the values that I could calculate them or if there is another way

Comment: Write a table using pen and paper and you'll be able to find out a formula that only requires one variable to hold the running total. For example, after generating 37.1, 38.2, 39.3, how would you calculate the average? It'd also look like your `ex4` should not be an integer.

Comment: FYi: For loop will run 101 times. Do you want to print the average on every iteration? Or final average?

Comment: Why do you have this? Are you only counting the numbers within that range?
if (num > 36.6 && num< 37.6)  {}

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0,101).Average(_=>rnd.NextDouble()*(MAX-MIN)+MIN)`

Comment: return (MIN + MAX)/2.  I mean, it's going to converge to that the more rounds it does. What's the point of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ex4 a double, not an int.

Inside the loop, ex4 += num;

Print the average as ex4 / 101.

Comment: It's better to create a collection and then devide by it's count, because there can be more than 100 measurements

Comment: @Mateech If this code is just doing this one thing, it doesn't need to create a collection, but it would be good to put 101 in a constant or variable, and refer to it in both places, rather than listing the number twice. But I was just answering the question.

Comment: @Mateech -  it's not better to create a collection, it's a big waste of resources. Dronz's suggestion is reasonable

Answer (score 2):

Until now, all answers are telling you how to keep track of all values so that, afterwards, you can take the average.

However, this is not the best approach, the best approach is to keep track of two values:

- The sum of the values
- The amount of the values

Once you have finished your loop, you just divide the sum by the average, and the result is the average.

In pseudo-code:

```
double sum = 0;
int amount = 0;

for (...)
{
    value = random_calculation();
    sum = sum + value;
    amount = amount + 1;
}

write_to_output(sum / amount);
```

This approach is better because you only keep track of 2 values in memory. If you keep track of all values, you occupy 100 memory spaces.
Obviously, for just 100 values, this is negligible, but imagine you want to do the same for millions of values, you might get into RAM related problems.

Comment: My answer did not suggest keeping all of the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
    const double MAX = 42.0;
    const double MIN = 34.5;
    double ex4 = 0;
    int iterations=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
        if (num > 36.6 && num< 37.6)
        {
           ex4+=num;
           iterations++;
             Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num);
        }
       
    }
    ex4=ex4/iterations;
    Console.WriteLine("the average of the degres is: {0}",ex4);
```

`

Comment: I don't know your exact scenario but I think you should move the Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num); in to the if statement as well .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).